# Comparing two editTexts in android

Tags: android, string-comparison

I am learning android I tried following codeline but it's giving me error please give me suggestions, that how can I compare two `edittext`'s text.

```
if((edt1.getText().toString() && 
    edt4.getText().toString() && 
    edt7.getText().toString)=="X")
```

Comment: Just to be clear: What you want to do is check a variable number of strings, to see if all of them contain "X", is that right? So @hoipolloi has in fact answered your question correctly? (If so, please click the check-mark to the left of his answer to mark it as the accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that doesn't violate the DRY principle:

```
private static boolean allContain(final String value, 
                                  final EditText... editTexts)
{

    for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
        final String text = editText.getText().toString();
        if (!text.equals(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
if (allContain("X", edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4)) {
    // All EditTexts contain 'X'
}
```

Comment: what is the DRY principle ?

Comment: @Francisco - Don't Repeat Yourself

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
if((edt1.getText().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) && 
   (edt4.getText().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) && 
   (edt7.getText().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("X")))
```

If you have to compare strings then you need to call the `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` function of String.

Answer (score 1):

I have find the best solution..

```
if(Password.getText().toString().trim().matches(confirmPassword.getText().toString().trim()))
{
// then do your work
}
else
//otherwise show error message.
```

whereas

```
Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);

confirmPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirmpass);
```

are two editText.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( (edt1.getText().toString()=="X")&&(edt4.getText().toString()=="X")&&(edt7.getText().toString()=="X") )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check edt1, edt4, edt7 have "X" value then try this..

```
if((edt1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("X")     
               &&edt4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("X") && 
              edt7.getText().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Make it simple:

```
if (!et1.toString().equals(et2.toString())) {
    MsgBox(this,"--Your Message--");
}
```