# Comparing text in EditText

Tags: android

#### My code:

```
final EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

        
        et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if ( hasFocus )
                {
                    et1.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                    if ( et1.getText().equals("Email") ) { et1.setText(""); }
                }
                else
                { 
                    et1.setTextColor(0xFF7F7F7F);
                    if ( et1.getText().equals("") ) { et1.setText("Email"); }
                }
            }           
        });
```

et1 has "Email" in it by default. When the user clicks on it, I want it to clear.
The `OnFocusChangeListener` works fine as the color changes, but the text does not change, i.e. the

```
if ( et1.getText().equals("Email") )
```

doesn't fire. Nor does the `equals("")`, after I clear the et.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly, the string you're comparing to is neither "Email" nor "". Print it to Log and check what it actually is.

Comment: `et1.getText()` is obviously not returning "Email".  The compiler is not broken, break out your debugger and see exactly what it is returning.  EDIT: Ninja'd by an evil bag of candy...

Comment: See best solution here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567527/comparing-two-edittexts-in-android/24733327#24733327

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try comparing `et1.getText().toString().equals("Email")` instead.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But strange, I always thought getText() does return a string. :)

Comment: It doesn't, it returns an EditText or something similar. I really dislike Java (I know, that's an Android issue, but had Java had operator overloading, all this wouldn't have mattered one bit)

Answer (score 1):

Print out et1.getText() to see what it contains. It might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Why the downvote? Printing out variables is exactly the first step in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Would `android:hint` work for you?  It basically is doing exactly what you are trying to do, but it is built in.