# How to compare two edittext fields in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application i got two edit boxes,one is editPassword and other is editConfirmpassword.i want to compare data between those two boxes that both values are equal and only if they are equal then only write data in sharedpref file.

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567527/comparing-two-edittexts-in-android/24733327#24733327

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editConfirmpassword);
if(e1.getText().toString().equals( e2.getText().toString())){
//do things if these 2 are correct.
}
```

Comment: i have done it like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567527/comparing-two-edittexts-in-android/24733327#24733327

Comment: It will give true even if length is not same

Answer (score 1):

Use string comparison here. You can fetch the EditText value using `getText().toString();`
Now you can do a compare using [compareToIgnoreCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: can u please explain it little bit because i am new to android.thx

Comment: Please refer to @superuser's code. You can do a string match using == operator or `(e1.getText().toString().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getText().toString()) == 0)` // if it zero, the strings match ignoring the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this onCreate method to do the comparison. Use a button to confirm.

```
    final EditText pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);
    final EditText cpass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ConfirmPassword);
    final Button testButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Test);

     testButton.setOnClickListener(
         new View.OnClickListener()
         {
             public void onClick(View arg0)
             {
                 if(pass.getText().toString().equals(cpass.getText().toString())){
                    //Toast is the pop up message
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password match",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    //Toast is the pop up message
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
             }
         });
```