# Compare TextView and EditText Values

Tags: java, android

I am trying to *compare EditText value with TextView*, but always getting "**Does not match !**"

Is this the wrong way to compare two values ?

For an example : I have stored **win** in *TextView* and entering same **win** in *EditText* but getting ***Does Not Match*** ......

```
    EditText editPassword;
    String strPassword;
    TextView lblPassword;
    String password;
    String strMatch;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

        editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

        strPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        password = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PASSWORD);

        lblPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password_label);

        lblPassword.setText(password);

        strMatch= lblPassword.getText().toString();        

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(strPassword.equals(strMatch))
                {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Match !",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  editPassword.setText(null);
                }
                else 
                {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Does not match !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });        
    }
```

Comment: Just a word of advice. Learn how to set breakpoints in your code and run the app in debug mode. This will allow you to examine the values of variables as the app is running, and understand why they don't match.

Comment: See best Solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567527/comparing-two-edittexts-in-android/24733327#24733327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your `onClick` method of the `Buttton`

```
 strPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();
```

Present your edittext value is empty string means `""`

Comment: but why inside the onClick(...)

Comment: at first time there is no data in editext..after data entered you will press button..now edittext has data..you are getting that..

Comment: ohhh... yes in onCreate() EditText's initial value is null, so how it could be possible to match with some other field, without having any data into EditText.... anyways thanks for help

Comment: after getting data from edittext only you can perform your desired opearation.until then then you cant..or you can directly set the data with hardcoding..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 strPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();
```

line inside of your onClick() event

```
 In your case the edit text value is always to be ""
```

Comment: @kalyanpvs oop yess i agree that

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editPassword;
    String strPassword;
    TextView lblPassword;
    String password;
    String strMatch;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

        editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);



        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        password = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PASSWORD);

        lblPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password_label);

        lblPassword.setText(password);



        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              strPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();
              strMatch= lblPassword.getText().toString(); 

                if(strPassword.equals(strMatch))
                {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Match !",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  editPassword.setText(null);
                }
                else 
                {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Does not match !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the ORDER of your lines. You first assign ONCE at the beginning something to strPassword and strMatch, and then you change the underlying controls (maybe even by editing something in your GUI), but your onClick() method still compares the values you initially stored in strPassword and strMatch.

Try replacing

```
if(strPassword.equals(strMatch))
```

with

```
if(editPassword.getText().equals(lblPassword.getText()))
```

(or append `toString()` to each, I don't remember if `toString()` is needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
if(strPassword.trim().equals(strMatch.trim()))
```