# String comparing containing special characters and comma

Tags: java, android, string-matching

I am developing a application in which i am comparing strings, all strings return true, when string contains `comma` then it returns false. e.g

```
String a= edittext.getText().toString().toTrim(); // e.g "string,"
String b= textView.getText().toString().toTrim(); // e.g "string,";

if(a.equals(b)){
Log.i("LOG","Matched!");
}else{
Log.i("LOG","Not Matched!");
}
```

I don't know `equals` function return false on this type of string. 
Help how to match these types of strings.

Comment: Sting b= "string,";? 

String not Sting

Comment: Does your code compile. What's Sting? Also, there is no reason for equals method to return false if you change Sting to String

Comment: and you should use TextUtils.equals() to compare strings. It doesn't throw a NPE

Comment: @schopy  `TextUtils.equals()` also return false.

Comment: @faisalahsan What is the output? What are you expecting the output to be? Does it output "LOG","Matched!

Answer (score 2):

It returns false because of your typos! You missed an *r* in string b declaration.

### Keep your eyes peeled next time!

Correction:

```
String a="string,";
String b= "string,";

if(a.equals(b)){
Log.i("LOG","Matched!");
}else{
Log.i("LOG","Not Matched!");
}
```

Comment: it was just a typing mistake,i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem?
Your code in your (updated) question works just fine.

it returns (as expected) "Matched!"

Comment: actually value `a` , i am getting from `EditText` and value `b` from `TextView`.

Comment: Then you will have probably a problem with whitespaces?. Try to "trim()" both of your values.    EDIT: oh i see you did that already ... Then just print out the 2 values und look what they really are.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654695/compare-textview-and-edittext-values